# convert java.util.Date to datastax's LocalDate

Tags: java, date, cassandra, datastax, localdate

I'm trying to convert a date in `yyyy-MM-dd` String format to datastax's LocalDate. I'm using following code to do that.

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

public static LocalDate getDate(String date) throws ParseException {
    Date d = DATE_FORMAT.parse(date);
    return LocalDate.fromMillisSinceEpoch(d.getTime());
}
```

When I tested this method I'm not getting expected results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    System.out.println(getDate("2017-11-22"));
}
// Actual Output:
2017-11-21
// Excpected Output:
2017-11-22
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: What does `Date d` output?

Comment: A timezone issue. When it‘s 22 November 00:00:00 in your time zone, it’s still 21 November in UTC, which I expect that `LocalDate.fromMillisSinceEpoch()` uses since you din’t tell it a time zone.

Comment: Date d is giving `Wed Nov 22 00:00:00 IST 2017` output. I checked it's epoch value in JavaScript and it is also giving `Wed Nov 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`.

Comment: The `SimpleDateFormat` class is long outdated and notoriously troublesome. Also for your task `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, is clearly better suited, so I recommend you use it instead of `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Ole V.V.'s solution is more elegant than mine... I always forget about new Date API...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
public static LocalDate convertDate(final String date) {
    String[] arr = date.split("-");
    if (arr.length != 3)
        return null;
    return LocalDate.fromYearMonthDay(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]),
            Integer.parseInt(arr[1]),
            Integer.parseInt(arr[2]));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

```
public static LocalDate getDate(String date) {
    java.time.LocalDate jtld = java.time.LocalDate.parse(date);
    return LocalDate.fromYearMonthDay(jtld.getYear(), jtld.getMonthValue(), jtld.getDayOfMonth());
}
```

### java.time

The Java date and time classes you are using, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, are long outdated and poorly designed, and the latter in particular has proven troublesome. Furthermore, `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, provides a class also called `LocalDate` that matches your need much better than the outdated `Date` class. `java.time.LocalDate` is a date without time of day. So using it completely eliminates the time zone issue that caused your problem. Your string, `2017-11-22`, is in ISO 8601 format, which `LocalDate` parses as its default, that is, without any explicit formatter, which also makes your task easier.

### What went wrong in your code?

Your `SimpleDateFormat` instance defaults to using the time zone setting of your JVM (probably Asia/Kolkata time) and therefore parses your date string into the equivalent of Wed Nov 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST), which in turn is the same point in time as November 21, 2017, at 18:30 UTC. The documentation of `LocalDate.fromMillisSinceEpoch()` says: “if the given number does not correspond to a whole number of days, it will be rounded towards 0.” In other words, it rounds to 2017-11-21.

If you really insist on sticking with the oldfashioned `SimpleDateFormat`, I wish you good luck (sorry, you may need it). If so, assign it a time zone of UTC, and it will parse into a date in UTC, and your existing method will work no matter the time zone setting of the JVM.

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = buildOldfashionedDateFormatInstance();

private static SimpleDateFormat buildOldfashionedDateFormatInstance() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
    return dateFormat;
}
```

### Links

- [Oracle Tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)
- [`com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate.fromMillisSinceEpoch()` documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/LocalDate.html#fromMillisSinceEpoch-long-)

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that there is some messing up because of the time-zone of your date. To check this simply print also the hours and minutes of the result. I wouldn't be surprised if it is something like
2017-11-21 23:00

Than you can simply fix it by making sure that the date does nit change because of a 'little time-zone difference'.

To make sure that a few hours difference in your date do not mess up the day you can do this (**only if you are not interested in the time part of the date**)

replace:

```
return LocalDate.fromMillisSinceEpoch(d.getTime())
```

by (add 12 h to make sure that a few hours +/- do not change the day)

```
return LocalDate.fromMillisSinceEpoch(d.getTime()+1000*60*60*12)
```

Comment: I agree in your diagnosis. Your solution is fragile. The user’s time zone could be at UTC+13:00 or +14:00, in which case adding 12 hours will not be enough. It may also be to the other side, at UTC-13:00 or -14:00, in which case adding 12 hours will give you the following day (November 23 when November 22 was expected). Better to do an explicit conversion from user’s time zone to UTC.

Comment: Date d is giving `Wed Nov 22 00:00:00 IST 2017` output. I checked it's epoch value in JavaScript and it is also giving `Wed Nov 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`.

Comment: @Ole V.V: I agree it is fragile. So only use it if you are sure that it fits your needs. I solved a similar problem this way but I could be sure that all Dates where in UTC+1:00. (and an extra 1h offset in winter).

Comment: Assumptions are dangerous. An assumption that your program will always run at UTC+1 or +2, or always at UTC+05:30, should at least be checked so you can make sure your program crashes rather than giving incorrect result, should the assumption break one day. Of course you can check the time zone of the JVM, but it’s already starting to get complicated for my taste…